# showing a login view after moving an image - facebook login, ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-animation, grand-central-dispatch

Given :

```
 1.logo 
 2.viewA contains:
    a.username (uitextfield)
    b.password (uitextfield)
    c.login button
```

Goal

```
1. shift a logo upward
2. when shifting is done, the view will be shown
```

**FIRST APPROACH**

Using [UIView animateWithDuration: options: animations: completion:]

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.4 delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{
                     CGRect     newFrame   =   self.logo.frame;
                     newFrame.origin.y     =   29;
                     self.logo.frame       =   newFrame;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     self.viewA.alpha      =   1;

                 }
 ];
```

This one works perfectly for me

However, I am still persuading a second approach below

**SECOND APPROACH**

First to shift the logo upward , I am doing

```
   CABasicAnimation *theAnimation;
   theAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.translation.y"];
   theAnimation.duration=1;
   theAnimation.autoreverses=NO;

   theAnimation.fromValue           =  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
   theAnimation.toValue             =  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:-60];
   theAnimation.removedOnCompletion =  NO;
   theAnimation.fillMode            =  kCAFillModeForwards;
   [self.flipgiveLogo1.layer addAnimation:theAnimation forKey:@"animateLayer"];
```

Secondly, I can do

```
self.viewA.alpha                    =  1;
```

to show the view. Sadly, the operations are not executed in order.

It is unlikely first approach that *block* is used to guarantee operations executed in order.
I did try using Grand Central Dispatch like below

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);  
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   // shifting logo goes here

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //displaying viewA goes here
    });
});
```

This still is bugging me.
Please help,if you know what I am doing wrong with GCD here. All comments are appreciated here

Comment: the block works?  use the block.  blocks are good.

Comment: @danh:can you tell me more about this. Familiar with blocks but no idea how to use it in this case.